# kubectl can't connect to Google Container Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have followed the installation steps:
https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook#install_gcloud_and_kubectl

A Google Container Engine cluster is up and running and gcloud CLI is authenticated and works.

But kubectl says: 
    `"couldn't read version from server: Get http://local host:8080/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused"`

I think I need to use `kubectl config set-cluster` to setup the connection to my cluster on GCE.

Where do I find the address of the Kubernetes master of my GCE cluster?
With `gcloud beta container clusters list` I seemingly get the master IP of my cluster.
I used that with `kubectl config set-cluster`.

Now it says:
    `"error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://     104.197.49.119/api: dial tcp 104.197.49.119:80: i/o timeout"`

Am I on the right track with this?

Additional strangeness:

- `gcloud container` or `gcloud preview container` doesn't work for me. Only `gcloud beta container`
- MASTER_VERSION of my cluster is 0.21.4, while the version of my kubectl client is GitVersion:"v0.20.2", even though freshly installed with gcloud.

Comment: gcloud preview was deprecated. You can use gcloud beta container (preferred) or gcloud alpha container instead.

Comment: gcloud container is out of beta currently.

Answer (score 30):

Run

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster-name`

to update the kubeconfig file and point kubectl at a cluster on Google Container Engine.

Comment: It's `gcloud container clusters get-credentials <name-of-cluster>` in the current version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684761/cant-get-credentials-for-google-container-cluster

Answer (score 1):

as @ScyDev stated
Run:
`gcloud container get-credentials <cluster_name>`
But you may have to set your compute zone before, in case you initialized a new cloud shell terminal. That was my case

if you're working in windows (ex. powershell), you need to check this out:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34395